# groupBy or partitioning object with multiple keys with lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have an array of packets so that each packet has source IP and destination IP.
I want to find the best way to divide the array so that in the end I'll get a dictionary whose keys are IP and their value is all the packets sent from or to that IP.

For example, if this is my array:

```
let packets = [ {sourceIp:127.0.0.1, destIp:127.0.0.2}, 
                {sourceIp:127.0.0.2, destIp:127.0.0.3},
                {sourceIp:127.0.0.3, destIp:127.0.0.1},
                {sourceIp:127.0.0.2, destIp:127.0.0.1}]
```

I'm looking for a way to get-

```
result = { 127.0.0.1: [{sourceIp:127.0.0.1, destIp:127.0.0.2},{sourceIp:127.0.0.3, destIp:127.0.0.1},
                       {sourceIp:127.0.0.2, destIp:127.0.0.1}],
           127.0.0.2: [{sourceIp:127.0.0.1, destIp:127.0.0.2},{sourceIp:127.0.0.2, destIp:127.0.0.3},
                       {sourceIp:127.0.0.2, destIp:127.0.0.1}],
           127.0.0.3: [{sourceIp:127.0.0.2, destIp:127.0.0.3},{sourceIp:127.0.0.3, destIp:127.0.0.1}]
         }
```

Thank you:-)

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Could you add a specific question? StackOverflow is not here to do the programming for you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all json array objects data type should be in string.

Then use *lodash* in [_.groupBy()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy)

```js
const packets = [{
    sourceIp: "127.0 .0 .1",
    destIp: "127.0 .0 .2"
  },
  {
    sourceIp: "127.0 .0 .2",
    destIp: "127.0 .0 .3"
  },
  {
    sourceIp: "127.0 .0 .3",
    destIp: "127.0 .0 .1"
  },
  {
    sourceIp: "127.0 .0 .2",
    destIp: "127.0 .0 .1"
  }
]
const splittedData = _.groupBy(packets, 'sourceIp');
console.clear();
console.log(splittedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This only groups by sourceIp. The question wants groups based on *either* source or destination (and as a result, output data has twice as many elements).

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1: Create both perspectives

Presuming `sourceIp` & `destinationIp` are always different (which seems reasonable), I would first duplicate the array so that you have 1 with source as "key", and 1 with destination as "key":

```
const packetsBySource = packets.map(({ sourceIp, destIp }) => ({ key: sourceIp, sourceIp, destIp }))
const packetsByDest = packets.map(({ sourceIp, destIp }) => ({ key: destIp, sourceIp, destIp }))
```

### Step 2: Merge & groupBy

Then I would merge these together, and do a groupBy:

```
import groupBy from 'lodash/groupBy'

const both = [...packetsBySource, ...packetsByDest]
const keyed = groupBy(both, 'key')
```

### Notes

- Your objects will still have the extra `key` property; if this is a problem you will need: `const keyedClean = mapValues(keyed, (packets) => packets.map(({ sourceIp, destIp }) => ({ sourceIp, destIp })))`
- If you have a *really* big input array then performance might become important; it might be faster to use groupBy twice on the original array, and then merge the 2 result objects (I don't know off-hand a quick way to merge array properties)